# MS Access ADODB.recordset character limit is 2036!? Can this be increased?

Tags: ms-access-2007, adodb, recordset

In the following AccessVBA code, I am trying to write a record to a memo field called "Recipient_Display":

oRec1.Fields("RECIPIENT_DISPLAY") = Left(sRecipientDisplayNames, Len(sRecipientDisplayNames) - 2)

When the string contains 2036 characters, the write completes. Above this number I get the following error:

Run-time error'-2147217887(80040e21)':
Could not update; currently locked by another session on this machine.

What is the significance of this number 2036 and is there a property I can adjust that will allow the above update to take place?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is the string that is the problem? The message is usual when working with unsaved project and ADO.

BTW you should be using DAO with Access and VBA.